# Error insert statement conflicted with the foreign key constraint

Tags: sql-server, database

### Issue

I have to table "Account_Manager" and "Partner" and both table contains foreign Key of each other and now I want to add data and it show the error Foreign Key conflict issue.
Guide me how I can insert data into these two table.

### Table 1

[image]

---

### Table 2

[image]

Comment: which db are you using? what did you try to do? did you try write some insert? can you post more details?

Comment: I am using MSSQL SERVER

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make both columns (*designated as FKs*) nullable. Thats only way you can make circular reference/FK